# R: cannot install packages with install.packages() in ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu

Operation system: Ubuntu 12

R version: 3.3.1

When I try to install packages by install.packages() shows the following errors:

```html
install.packages("cluster")
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Warning: failed to download mirrors file (cannot download all files); using local file '/opt/R/lib/R/doc/CRAN_mirrors.csv'
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://mirrors.opencas.cn/cran/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'http://mirrors.opencas.cn/cran/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning messages:
1: In download.file(url, destfile = f, quiet = TRUE) :
  URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/CRAN_mirrors.csv': status was 'Couldn't connect to server'
2: package ?.luster?.is not available (for R version 3.3.1)
```

I have tried other mirrors but still does't work. It seems that the R cannot connect to the network. In my company there is neccessary to connect network by proxy. Therefore, I have set the proxy for R by edit ~/.Renviron and this has been checked:

```html
> Sys.getenv("http_proxy")
[1] "http://proxy.zte.com.cn:80/"
> Sys.getenv("https_proxy")
[1] "https://proxy.zte.com.cn:80/"
> Sys.getenv("ftp_proxy")
[1] "ftp://proxy.zte.com.cn:80/"
```

But it still cannot work. And then, I test the R whether can connect to network by the following function and the FALSE is returned.

```html
library('curl')

has_internet <- function(){
+   !is.null(curl::nslookup("r-project.org", error = FALSE))
+ }
                
> has_internet()
[1] FALSE
```

Is there anybody having idea about this? Many thanks for attention.

Comment: You're using the "Run code snippet" on things that can't be run. That's for JS.

Comment: The problem as you said is just network access. It would be easiest to troubleshoot this on Server Fault, but what you can do as some diagnostics is to try to ping google.com from your terminal and if it works then just copy the settings used with the terminal. Also, check out the various settings mentioned in this thread and see if any work for you https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200660383-Proxy-settings

Comment: there's an argument "method" in `install.packages` which uses the methods from `download.file`, according to `?download.file` you can set this to "wget" or "curl", these use a system call, so if those work properly on your system, this ought to get around the proxy.

Comment: I think the `HTTPS_PROXY` var must be upper case

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have tried all these but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think the CRAN mirror you use does not work. Try

```
options(repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org")
```

What OS do you use? If you are on windows, what do you get for:

```
curl::ie_proxy_info()
curl::ie_get_proxy_for_url("https://cloud.r-project.org")
```

Try `method = "wininet"` to let R download files via the windows API rather than libcurl:

```
install.packages("MASS", repos = "https://cran.r-project.org") method = "wininet)
```

If that does not work the machine is basically offline. 
If `curl::has_internet()` fails it means you don't have a connection at all, at least not a functioning DNS server.

Comment: My OS is Ubuntu, therefore it seems not to work. Thank you anyway.

Comment: For those like me who end up here by way of search - underscoring the possibility is that the URL - in my case CRAN itself right now - is down.